# How to save pyspark model in to pickle file

Tags: python, pyspark

How to save pyspark model in to pickle file

```
  final_data=output_fixed.select('features','CreditabilityIndex')

  test=final_data.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

  dtc=DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol='CreditabilityIndex',featuresCol='features')

  dtc_model=dtc.fit(train)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the model using `save()` method where `spark` is a `SparkContext` object: [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.tree.DecisionTreeModel.save)

```
dtc_model.save(spark, "/path/to/file")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save your models in this fashion too -

```
lr = LogisticRegression(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features")
lr_model = lr.fit(train2)
lr_model.save("abc.model")

###This is how you can load it back - 
sameModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load("abc.model")
```

PS - It will be saved in the location of your code file. However, sometimes you may not be able to see the actual file. But it will be saved for you to load again. So nothing to worry about.